# Get data as string from ftp

Tags: php, ftp, gd

Is is possible to get data from ftp as string? I want to create image via `imagecreatefromstring`, but not found any ftp function of it. I need it because i am afraid that it would be possible to upload a third party php code instead of images.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch the contents of a file as a string through FTP with this code:

```
function ftp_get_string($ftp, $filename) {
    $temp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    if (@ftp_fget($ftp, $temp, $filename, FTP_BINARY, 0)) {
        rewind($temp);
        return stream_get_contents($temp);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

`$ftp` would be an FTP connection resource returned by [`ftp_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php).

**Disclaimer:** The code isn't mine; it's almost verbatim from the comments for [`ftp_fget`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php) at php.net.

Comment: @NoNameZ: Then it will be downloaded to a temporary file. You can use `php://memory` if you want to avoid this, but then you risk running out of memory if the file is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use [`php://output`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) with [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
/**
 * @param $ftp ftp connexion id
 * @param $filename distant file name
 * @return a string with file content or FALSE
 */ 
function ftp_get_string($ftp, $filename) {
    ob_start();
    $result = ftp_get($ftp, "php://output", $filename, FTP_BINARY);
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $result === FALSE ? false : $data;
}
```